# Using Log4j2 properties file in multiple webapps on Tomcat is going to the wrong log file or console log only or none at all

Tags: logging, log4j2, console.log, properties-file, tomcat9

I have 2 properties files but the second goes to the first log file or to the console only and not to the log file specified. Below only goes to the console and not either log file. Using log4j-api-2.18.0.jar and log4j-core-2.18.0.jar locally for each app and in the lib folder of Tomcat.

```
# Extra logging related to initialization of Log4j
# Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing
status = debug
# Name of the configuration
name= CMS-Config

# Log files location
property.basePath = ${sys:catalina.home}/logs

appenders = cmsConfig

# RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appender.cmsConfig.type = RollingFile
appender.cmsConfig.name = cmsConfig_Logger
appender.cmsConfig.createOnDemand = true
appender.cmsConfig.fileName= ${basePath}/cms_config.log
appender.cmsConfig.filter=
appender.cmsConfig.filePattern= ${basePath}/app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.cmsConfig.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.cmsConfig.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.cmsConfig.policies.type = Policies

# RollingFileAppender rotation policy
appender.cmsConfig.policies.startup.type = OnStartupTriggeringPolicy
appender.cmsConfig.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.cmsConfig.policies.size.size = 50MB
appender.cmsConfig.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.cmsConfig.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.cmsConfig.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.cmsConfig.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.cmsConfig.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.cmsConfig.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.cmsConfig.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.cmsConfig.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified

# Delete all files older than 3 days
appender.cmsConfig.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 3d

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue} %c{1}:%L - %m%n

loggers = cms_config

# Classes in this package or sub packages will use ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender for logging         
logger.cms_config.name = com.dancik.cms
logger.cms_config.level = ERROR
logger.cms_config.additivity = false
logger.cms_config.appenderRefs = cmsConfig
logger.cms_config.appenderRef.cms_config.ref = cmsConfig_Logger
logger.cms_config.appenderRef.cms_config.level = ERROR
logger.cms_config.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.additivity = false
# Root logger referring to console appender
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = cmsConfig_Logger
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
```

This version of the file above goes to the log file that is below this log file but not to the one listed.

```
# Extra logging related to initialization of Log4j
# Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing
status = ERROR
# Name of the configuration
name= CMS-Config

# Log files location
property.basePath = ${sys:catalina.home}/logs

# RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.createOnDemand = true
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}/cms_config.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}/app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

# RollingFileAppender rotation policy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 50MB
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified

# Delete all files older than 3 days
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 3d

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue} %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = ERROR
# Root logger referring to console appender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
```

if it does go to a log file this is the one it does go to but is a separate properties file in a different app all together.

```
# Extra logging related to initialization of Log4j
# Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing
status = ERROR
# Name of the configuration
name= Accounting

# Log files location
property.basePath = ${sys:catalina.home}/logs

# RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}/accounting.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}/app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies

# RollingFileAppender rotation policy
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 50MB
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified

# Delete all files older than 3 days
appender.rolling.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 3d

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue} %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = ERROR
# Root logger referring to console appender
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = fileLogger
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I just had to create a logger name and add a log appenderRef as well that was unique for each app. I also changed the status to trace and added additivity. I also noticed that the rolling appender for root had to be before console.

Here is the code:

```
# Extra logging related to initialization of Log4j
# Set to debug or trace if log4j initialization is failing
status = trace
# Name of the configuration
name= Accounting

# Log files location
property.basePath = ${sys:catalina.home}/logs

appenders = accounting

# RollingFileAppender name, pattern, path and rollover policy
appender.accounting.type = RollingFile
appender.accounting.name = accounting_Logger
appender.accounting.createOnDemand = true
appender.accounting.fileName= ${basePath}/accounting.log
appender.accounting.filePattern= ${basePath}/app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.accounting.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.accounting.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.accounting.policies.type = Policies

# RollingFileAppender rotation policy
appender.accounting.policies.startup.type = OnStartupTriggeringPolicy
appender.accounting.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.accounting.policies.size.size = 50MB
appender.accounting.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.accounting.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.accounting.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.accounting.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.accounting.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.accounting.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}/accounting.log
appender.accounting.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.accounting.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified

# Delete all files older than 3 days
appender.accounting.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 3d

# Console appender configuration
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = consoleLogger
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%level}{FATAL=bg_red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue} %c{1}:%L - %m%n

loggers = accounting_log

# Classes in this package or sub packages will use ConsoleAppender and RollingFileAppender for logging
logger.accounting_log.name = com.dancik.gl
logger.accounting_log.level = error
logger.accounting_log.additivity = false
logger.accounting_log.appenderRefs = log_accounting
logger.accounting_log.appenderRef.log_accounting.ref = accounting_Logger
logger.accounting_log.appenderRef.log_accounting.level = trace
logger.accounting_log.appenderRef.console.ref = consoleLogger

# Root logger level
rootLogger.level = trace
rootLogger.additivity = false
# Root logger referring to console appender
rootLogger.appenderRef.accounting.ref = accounting_Logger
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = consoleLogger
```